# Gratis Mahjong solitaire for Windows, which is *NOT* from the Microsoft app store

Tags: windows, gratis, game

The title says it all.

Obviously, more features, etc. would be better (although classic tiles are all that is required), but I will accept anything that does not require downloading it from the MS app store

Comment: @EricS - Probably. I would recommend that the querent also search the bingleduck for "Shanghai game", as several mahjong solitaires are sold under that name.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You'll have to tell us, what's a *bingleduck*?  Regardless of the meaning, I love the word. ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket -  "bingleduck" - portmanteau of "BING, gooGLe, DUCKduckgo"; intended usage as a somewhat nonbiased term for search engine, generically. Coined to avoid comments like "I hate Google" in response to suggestions like "Did you google it?".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Now I love the word even more! Well done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer [PySol-FC](https://pysolfc.sourceforge.io/) (python solitaire fan club edition) which:

- Is free, gratis & Open Source definitely **not** Microsoft
- Is available for most common platforms including Windows, Linux & OS-X
- By default contains 200 Mahjongg layouts *as a part of the total 1069 solitaire variants*
- Multiple card sets included by default and additional ones available or you can make your own.
- There are installers for Windows >XP(sp3) and for Android (on F-driod) or it can be run from source. More information [here](https://github.com/shlomif/PySolFC).

[image]

Comment: Ha ha ha ha ha ha ha !! I should have known that you would find a way to involve Python :-)  Anyone reading this, do not worry, you don't have to install Python, it is compiled into a Windows executable and has an incredible number of solitaire type games, not just Mah Jong. Highly recommended !

Comment: Of course Mawg! No you don't __have__ to install Python on Windows or even on most a Linux machines (pysolfc or pysol-fc) is available as a package for most distributions. Even runs  nicely on a Raspberry Pi.